# Unable to login with users created via dbContext in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to seed the db with initial data and I am using the following code to create the users. Users get created, passwords hashed, etc but when I try to login with my password, it fails to log me in with error message: `Invalid login attempt`. What am I doing wrong? I am using asp.net core mvc application with identity template, not a custom login.

```
        var mymail = "my@my.com";
        var mypw = "Test1.";
        var applicationUsers = new ApplicationUser[]
        {
            new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = Constants.AnonUserName,
                Email = "Anonymous@xyz.com"
            },
            new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = mymail,
                Email = mymail
            }
        };
        var pwHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
        applicationUsers.ToList().ForEach(u =>
        {
            u.PasswordHash = pwHasher.HashPassword(u, mypw);
            context.ApplicationUsers.Add(u);
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: what is `nihatpw` ? Also what does `it fails to log me in` mean? What did you observe while debugging? Exception? password mis-match? something else?

Comment: I just added their values. I get Invalid login attempt. I assumed that asp.net identity uses different kind of hashing than mine (well, I checked the source code in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity UserManager and it is the same)

Comment: Did you try debugging with breakpoints and watching hashed passwords values to see if they are the same ?

Comment: Whats in the database, did you check the values in the columns to see if that is all correct?

Comment: @Rafalon, I did not, I will investigate like you said and report back.

Comment: **Don't use** the DbContext to populate/seed your database. With it you are bypassing all security / configuration of ASP.NET Core Identity! i.e. your password won't validated to enforce password policy (min length of password, or enforce capital/lower case letters with numbers and special characters) or any other constraints on the user name (email or username for login etc.)

Comment: @Tseng I am on a development machine and I don't care about those for now. I could have used userManagerInstance.createAsync to create the user but UserManager service is not available to me (I call my seeding method at the end of Configure method in Startup.cs and UserManager service is not available at that moment).

Comment: Of course it is available. When you can resolve DbContext you can also Resolve Usermanager. Just make sure to create a scope and dispose it, instead of resolving from `app.ApplicationServices`. The Container is built after `ConfigureServices` and is available before `Configure` gets called, see [SO Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-core/1949/dependency-injection/17400/using-scoped-services-during-application-startup-database-seeding#t=201705031555214489321)

Comment: @Tseng Waow, it did work. Thanks!! I don't know what I was doing wrong earlier. I guess  once things go bad, your mind screws up too :) This solves my problem of seeding db but I still want to debug why my earlier user creation was not allowing me to log in; I am obsessed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Login fails because `NormalizedUserName` field in db is null and during login, following query is issued (which fails):

```
SELECT "u"."Id", "u"."AccessFailedCount", "u"."ConcurrencyStamp", "u"."Email", "u"."EmailConfirmed", "u"."LockoutEnabled", "u"."LockoutEnd", "u"."NormalizedEmail", "u"."NormalizedUserName", "u"."PasswordHash", "u"."PhoneNumber", "u"."PhoneNumberConfirmed", "u"."SecurityStamp", "u"."TwoFactorEnabled", "u"."UserName"
    FROM "AspNetUsers" AS "u"
    WHERE "u"."NormalizedUserName" = $1
    LIMIT 1
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'MY@MY.COM'
```

I guess the solution is to inject ILookupNormalizer service and normalize with its `Normalize` method but it is already too much work. I am injecting UserManager service and using its CreateAsync method to create a user with a password as advised by @Tseng above in comments.